# How can I make ctrl +c log out my user in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox

[image: In the attached screenshot]

its a program called "menu general" Which translates to General Menu. Its a program that lets you choose one of the 7 options presented in the screenshot. The options that are written, are not important, the option that is important is the one that is called "salir" which means "exit". The task that I need to execute is when I select the 7th option which says exit, it will log me out of the system, instead of sending me back to the command prompt as it been shown in the image. My assignment is that I need to use ctrl +c as the logout execution instead of sending me back to prompt.

Comment: You should add more details about the attached screenshot. Additionally, it would be easier if it is in the same language (english) or if you translate it. You can also add more precise tags in order that people can find this question of yours.

Comment: thanks @chAlexey i will

Comment: I am not really into this problem. Can you add the description of which kind of program this is and where did you get it? Do you have a link? I see that it suggests you an option of ``[1 - 4]`` and it doesn't seem to correctly respond to ``[5 - 7]``. Am I right?